# How to use AngularJs with Servlet and Jsp

Tags: angularjs, servlets

I am developing a dynamic web project using JSP and Servlet.  Now I want to use AngularJs in my project. I need to know that where I can use the AngularJs and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP : server side templating.
This suffice the only requirement of providing a dynamic html page. Although the served html page will remain static on front end side, unless you make some ajax calls to the server, fetch the data and repaint the page on the fly.

Angular : front end javascript framework.
This obviously helps you templating webpages but is way more than that. While you can serve dynamic HTML pages using angular, you can leverage a long list of other benefits like adding data binding, utilizing MVC pattern, having services, control routing and so on...

So you can use angular on front end side and leverage its benefit without changing code at backend.

One piece of advice : there is hardly any use of JSP if you are already using angular on front end side. You can keep using JSP for server side templating but I do prefer velocity by oracle.